# Handling firebase auth with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

I am building a React + Redux + Firebase app with webpack and am trying to figure out the best way to handle protected routes and redirects. I have tried using `onEnter()` with `setTimeout()` like many examples show, but it still ended up flashing the alternate component before redirecting.

Here is what I currently have, and I am trying to come up with a more elegant solution. This mostly works, but an example of when it fails is if I am on `/profile` and navigate to `/` in the browser. It seems that because `firebase.auth()` needs to initialize again, I get a flash of the `HomePage` component before it switches to `Profile`.

Firebase is initialized in `firebaseClientConfig` and I am passing `firebase.auth()` in to `routes`.

```
import { auth } from './firebaseClientConfig';  

...    

export default (
<Route path="/" component={App}>    
 <IndexRoute
  getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return require.ensure([], require => {
          cb(null, require('./components/HomePage').default);
        });
      } else {
        return require.ensure([], require => {
          cb(null, require('./modules/Profile/Profile').default);
        });
      }
    });
  }}
/>
<Route
  path="/profile"
  getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        return require.ensure([], require => {
          cb(null, require('./modules/Profile/Profile').default);
        });
      } else {
        return require.ensure([], require => {
          cb(null, require('./modules/Login/Login').default);
        });
      }
    });
  }}
/>
</Route>
);
```

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: That's pretty elegant, nice!

Comment: @Bonitis I heard redux does not go well with firebase

Comment: @Ezeewei they actually work together beautifully! This question is outdated because react-router has gone from v3 -> v4, so there are major changes. In general, I have had no issues with redux+firebase.

Comment: @Bonitis ah nice! that's a really good news, myself was hesitating intergrating them together. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a `PrivateRoute` component and pass it an `authenticated` prop which I get from the redux store in the component where I use the `PrivateRoute`

When I login with firebase I put user data in the redux store. So in my case i would map state to props

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    authenticated: !!state.user.uid,
})
```

And give the authenticated prop to my `PrivateRoute` component

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authenticated, path, exact }) => {
  return (
      <Route
          path={path}
          exact={exact}
          render={props =>
            authenticated
              ? <Component {...props} />
              : <Redirect to="/login"/>}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: what happens when you refresh after log in? mine looks similar to yours but I find I get redirected to a new page

Comment: User properly with redux and a middlewhare, firebase should keep track of your auth state.

Answer (score 0):

if you are managing authentication using local state instead of redux then you need to create two states to hold progress of your authentication.

```js
state={"loading=true",
"loggedin=false"}
```

i.e. redner Loading component initialy when loading is true and when i receive current user state from firebase function i will use setState() to set loading to flase and further render the component i intend to render according to the user state.

For better understanding have look [react firebase authentication](https://link.medium.com/nulBJNzA63)

Answer (score 0):

I know is kind of late, but this might help others: You can find a slightly different approach [here](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/recipes/auth.html) (still with a private route so kind of similar to vhflat but I find it a little more clear and easy to implement).

Basically, in your private route you just

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
```

and

```
import { isLoaded } from 'react-redux-firebase'
```

After that you get the auth like this

```
const auth = useSelector( state => state.firebase.auth );
```

Then if the `isLoaded( auth )` is not true (so the auth state is not loaded) you can redirect to a loading page or just return a `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` if you don't want.

In the end if on your return, you can check if `!isEmpty( auth )`, and if that is true return the children component, otherwise Redirect to the login page or any other page you prefer.